# What's the easiest way to display NULL value as empty string instead of "null" string in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: php, mysql, null, extjs, grid

I have a server-side script (PHP) returning JSON data to populate an ExtJS Grid.

This data comes from a MySQL query, containing some NULL values.

When PHP encodes it into the JSON notation, it keeps the NULL intact:

```
{"id":"33","name":"Test1","url":null,"cls":"x-tree-noicon","expanded":true}
```

But... when this data is displayed in the ExtJS grid, it shows a "**null**" string in the place of the NULL value.

I don't want it to display "**null**". I just want it empty (an empty string).

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the easiest but the first thing that comes to my mind is creating a custom `renderer`. You can use something like this:

```
function render(value){
    if(value === null){
        value = '';
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: You replied fast and moved me forward in the right direction... My first try was to add the following configuration to the column:

renderer: function(value){ return( value === null ? '' : value ) }

It would have worked IF my was grid was not a treegrid. I will post more information as another answer for this...

Answer (score 2):

WoLpH's answer is correct. My own question was somehow "incorrect"... :-)

In fact, I am dealing with a **[treegrid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html)** (Ext.ux.tree.TreeGrid), not a common ExtJS grid (Ext.grid.GridPanel).

The columns of the treegrid are **not** of [Ext.grid.Column](http://localhost/ext/docs/?class=Ext.grid.Column) type, as the common grid. They are of **[Ext.list.Column](http://localhost/ext/docs/?class=Ext.list.Column)** type.

This means that the **renderer** configuration option does not apply (it exists and works on Ext.grid.Column, but not on Ext.list.Column).

To change the rendering of a Ext.list.Column, there is the **tpl** configuration option available, which uses the [Ext.XTemplate](http://localhost/ext/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate) mechanism.

Below, I share the configuration of my **treegrid** column that did what I wanted:

```
tpl: '<tpl if="url === null"></tpl><tpl if="url !== null">{url}</tpl>'
```

The configuration above made my column render an empty string for NULL values, instead of a "**null**" string, in the **treegrid**!

---

Final note: I voted on WoLpH's answer because it is correct. My question was misleading, and I preferred not to change/edit it, but to share my own findings as another answer. I also thank him because it made me focus on the right things. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for a treegrid it's a bit different. Good to know that you found a working solution. I actually considered an answer with a `TemplateColumn` but somehow that seemed overly complex to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your other option would be to handle it from the back end.  You would need to check in the result set for any instances of NULL and convert them to empty strings before returning it back to the client.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. In fact, I was almost doing this! But since I was able to find the workaround to handle this ExtJS issue in the client-side, I preferred to keep the PHP/JSON response "correct" (because NULL, in fact, is the correct value)...

Comment: Since you would need a renderer on every single column to prevent NULLs in every grid, it would be much easier the single NULL replacement serverside. Through just one array iterating function, you should be able to cover all returned cell values. You could also use reflection if you want to get fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Have you define an Ext.data.Model? if you define and Ext.data Model and the use it in the Ext.data.Store to read the JSON string  is very easy...

You just need to declare the field type: 'auto'

try this:

```
Ext.define('testModel', {
        extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields  :[
                     {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
                     {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                     {name: 'url', type: 'auto'},
                     {name: 'cls', type: 'string'},                     
                     {name: 'expanded', type: 'boolean'}
                  ]     
    });


var testStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                         model  : 'testModel',
                         proxy  : {
                                      type   : 'memory',
                                      reader : {type:'json'}
                                  }
                });
```

and use the testStore to fill up the data in your grid.

Comment: The original question and its answers are from August 2010 - this is two years ago, when Ext.data.Model didn't exist! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 3.4 there is a useNull property that can be set for a numeric field (not strings though).

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-useNull

> (Optional) Use when converting received data into a Number type
>   (either int or float). If the value cannot be parsed, null will be
>   used if useNull is true, otherwise the value will be 0. Defaults to
>   false
>
> Defaults to: false

E.g.

```
{
    name: 'myId',
    type: 'int',
    useNull: true
},
```